# C# Regex Sentences Splitter on period

Tags: c#, regex, nlp

I'm trying to find the period `.` that falls at the end of the sentence for the common cases. I have two deferent regexps that would do most of the job. The problem is that I need to combine them together, or vice versa, use one as the first set to exclude them and do the second and replace the first back. The example will show better.

Consider the following text.

> Abbreviations of units of measure are written without periods (with the exception of "in" when it could be confused with the preposition). We use periods for most lower-case abbreviations such as e.g. and i.e. and c.o.d. For very common abbreviations, leave out the periods, as in rpm and mph. When an abbreviation with a period ends a sentence, that period will suffice to end the sentence: He lives in Washington, D.C. Suffixes for people's names require periods: Joe Smith Jr. lives in Erie. In formal text it is not a good idea to abbreviate military titles — Lieutenant Colonel Chester Piascyk — but in informal text Lt. Col. Chester Piascyk would be acceptable. (Note the space after "Lt.") Academic degrees can be written with periods or not, but don't insert spaces — Ph.D. or PhD, M.B.A. or MBA — within the degree.check http://aaa.aaa.aaa this link www.google.com it is very good. Finally this is a reference (someone 2009).
>
> - Use a period after an initial. Example: `John F. Kennedy`.

Here is some list:

> 1. one list.
>      a. sub List.
>      A. another list.

Here are the two regexps I have.

```
(?<=( (?!((http?)|(www)))([^A-Z0-9 ]+)|( [0-9]*[)])))([\.])
(?<=([a-z]{3,}))([\.])
```

**Note** that I'm using this for a small NLP app, so I don't want to go with full NLP tools and I am also using regex in C#.NET environment.

Comment: How about a [little simpler regex](http://regex101.com/r/mX5dC2)? The only thing that I think is left are the title abbreviations for which you could add a list with alternations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is weird to answer my question in such a short time... but Here it is ...
I used this Regex (off course assuming abbreviations are no longer than 3 Chars.

> (?<=( (?!((http?)|(www)))([A-Z]?[a-z]{3,})|( [^ ]*[)])))([.])

And I tested it on this site http://regexhero.net/tester/
too bad the site it does not link like regex101.com but if you copy and paste both the text and Regex above you will see it works...

Comment: Actually Regex Hero has a permalink feature too. Go to Tools > Permalink.